# Visual Studio version mismatch

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssis

I am working on a SSRS project running SQL 2008 (Entity Data Model, DLL, SSIS, SSAS cubes)
Soon my team is going to need source control, we have Visual Studio 2012 set up. Upon check in Visual Studio 
updates the project files to 2012. When I pull down the project files they will 
no longer run on the original 2008 environment. Has anyone had any issues like this?
Please help me if there are any solutions.

Thank you

Comment: Don't open the solution or project file in the 2012 Visual Studio instance. Use it for the Team interactions (which can include code checkin/checkout). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this.

1. Right click on solution and say open with vs 2012
2. Create a new rs project in 2012 and add everything.

The easiest thing to do is just recreate the solution in 2012.

I have a number of solutions that I manage and I had to spend some time and do this for every single one of them.